# Django model forms able to save to db but unable to display in template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to save the inputs from my model form and it only saves the inputs to the db and doesn't display it on the template until I go to the db and click the save button. My form and the location where I display the submitted inputs are on the same HTML page. Why does this happen? I can't seem to find the reason. Please bear with me as I'm new to Django. Thanks in advance.

views.py:

```
def detail(request, pk):
    prof = get_object_or_404(Prof, pk=pk)
    ratings = Rating.objects.filter(slug=pk)

    paginator = Paginator(ratings, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    new_rating = None

    # rating posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rating_form = RatingForm(data=request.POST)
        if rating_form.is_valid():
            # Create Rating object but don't save to database yet
            new_rating = rating_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current prof to the rating
            new_rating.name = prof
            # Save the rating to the database
            new_rating.save()

    else:
        rating_form = RatingForm()

    return render(request, 'rating/detail.html', {'prof': prof, 'ratings': ratings, 'new_rating': new_rating, 'rating_form': rating_form, 'page_obj': page_obj})
```

template:

```
...

<p class="centerize mt-4">{{ ratings.count }} {% if ratings.count > 1 or ratings.count == 0 %} ratings {% else %} rating {% endif %}</p>
{% for rating in page_obj %}
    <div class="rating-container-detail">
        <div class="card border-secondary">
            <div class="card-header">{{ rating.subject }} - {{ rating.year }} <span class="float-right"> {{ rating.created_on|date:'F j, Y' }} </span></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-title">Helpfulness: <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"> {{ rating.helpfulness }}</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                    Pedagogy: <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"> {{ rating.pedagogy }} </span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                    Easiness: <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"> {{ rating.easiness }} </span>
                </p>
                <p class="card-text">{{ rating.comment | linebreaks }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% empty %}

    <p class="centerize">No ratings were found for this professor. <br> You may create one if you like: <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#create"> create a review</a></p>
{% endfor %}


...

<div class="ml-auto mr-auto mt-4" style="width: 40%;">
    {% if new_rating %}
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            Successfully created rating 
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'rating-detail' prof.pk %}">
            {{ rating_form | crispy }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
</div>

...
```

models.py:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    helpfulness_choices = (
        (1, 'Very Unhelpful'),
        (2, 'Unhelpful'),
        (3, 'Moderate'),
        (4, 'Helpful'),
        (5, 'Very Helpful'),
    )

    pedagogy_choices = (
        (1, 'Very Low Pedagogy'),
        (2, 'Low Pedagogy'),
        (3, 'Moderate'),
        (4, 'High Pedagogy'),
        (5, 'Very High Pedagogy'),
    )

    easiness_choices = {
        (1, 'Very Difficult'),
        (2, 'Difficult'),
        (3, 'Moderate'),
        (4, 'Easy'),
        (5, 'Very Easy'),
    }

    name = models.ForeignKey(Prof, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ratings")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=110)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    helpfulness = models.IntegerField(choices=helpfulness_choices)
    pedagogy = models.IntegerField(choices=pedagogy_choices)
    easiness = models.IntegerField(choices=easiness_choices)
    comment = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Comment: after page refresh does it display ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I tried redirecting it to another page to see if it works that way but it doesnt

Comment: what do you mean by you are going to data base and save ? Do you mean Admin ?

Comment: When you save using template did you check what does get display in terminal ?

Comment: Did you get any error while saving ?

Comment: oh yes sorry about that. i meant the Django admin

Comment: yes i checked the terminal. it just says that i made a post and get request (get request for when i tested it to redirect to another page)

Comment: try to post question with minimum code , it will be strain to read and understand entire page, I mean you could avoid css and all

Comment: there are no errors when i save

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214446/discussion-between-anoop-k-george-and-jatl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue:

I just added

```
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

in my models and set it to true

then made "ratings" in my model detail like this:

```
ratings = prof.ratings.filter(active=True)
```

I can also do this by just making ratings like this:

```
ratings = prof.ratings.all()
```